# Difference between scanf and creating a FileHandler

Tags: objective-c

Hi I wanted to know what is the difference between creating a file handler to read from console and using the scanf ()?

Comment: The difference is that in the first case, you use `scanf()`, and in the second case, you are using `NSFileHandle`.

Comment: @H2CO3: So young and already so sarcastic ... :-)

Comment: @MartinR :-) And often regrets having been so. But sometimes things just ignite my anger. (And anyway, I've experienced things that would to at least some extent justify the sarcasm, or even better, some self-deprecating irony... :( )

Answer (score 2):

The two approaches differ in *style*. The C functions `scanf` *et al* work with C strings and take lots of *pointers* in a procedural manner; `NSFileHandle` *et al* work with Objective-C strings, tend to return single values rather than multiple via pointers, and are method-based.

The choice is up to you, e.g. if you need to simply read in numbers from the console using `scanf` might be the easier option - while you can read in numbers using the Objective-C classes the C functions are more direct here.

If using the C functions you must take all the usual care over valid pointers, buffer overruns, etc.

You can mix the two in the same code **however** care must be taken as they each do (some of) their own buffering so alternating them will probably "lose" you input/rearrange your output.

If your issue is that there is no `scanf` equivalent in Objective-C and you wish to use it parse some input while using Objective-C classes for the rest of the I/O then you can read your input as strings and then use `sscanf` (with appropriate conversion between C & Obj-C types) to parse those strings.

HTH.

Comment: Another issue is that `scanf()` is unintuitive, its usage is bloated with small, extremely-hard-to-perceive errors and quirks, and it should probably be avoided. `fread()` and `fgets()` are much better alternatives in a C program.

Comment: @H2CO3 - They're not really "alternatives" as they do something different. I wouldn't say that `scanf` is a thing of outstanding beauty, but in comparison to `printf` its not a carbuncle of design and it gets the job done. But enough on `stdio`, it is what it is.

Comment: Nope. Conversely, `printf()` is an useful function and its semantics make sense. That of `scanf()` do not. And the proposed functions are alternatives in the sense that there's nothing that could be done using `scanf()` but not with `fgets()` or `fread()`. It's a much better, less error-prone and easier to grok approach to get one unit of data (a block, a line) at a time, and then parse it using dedicated functions. One function shall do one job, and `scanf()` abuses its position by mixing I/O with parsing. It's horrible.

Comment: @H2CO3 - "One function shall do one job, and printf() abuses its position by mixing I/O with formatting. It's horrible." Enough on `stdio`.